# How do i plot multiple axvspan OR vspan's on a line plot when value is True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I'm trying to highlight on a line chart that has a line of stock price, and then a band above and below the stock price line.

I have a column whose value is "1" every time the stock price exceeds the bands, and Nan when the stock price is in between the lines.

I want to highlight the regions where the value is "1", or when the stock price exceeds the bands. This happens multiple times, and I am unable to find a way to create more than one vspan correctly.

I am using pandas. The dates are the x-axis and are indexed. Any help with this?

I've been looking at plotly extensively for a day now, but don't see it being possible. I am struggling to figure out how to use matplotlib for this.

In the code below, i am trying to compare "OPEN" (the column that is a 1 if price exceeds a band) and "AAPL.O", which is the ric variable that is the closing price

```py
def add_SMA_bands(data,ric):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[ric])
    SMAname = "SMA_{}".format(ric)
    SMAstd = "SMAstd_{}".format(ric)
    SMAUpper = "UpperBand_{}".format(ric)
    SMALower = "LowerBand_{}".format(ric)
    df[SMAname] = df["{}".format(ric)].rolling(SMA).mean()   
    df[SMAUpper] = df[SMAname] + (df["{}".format(ric)].rolling(SMA).std())*2
    df[SMALower] = df[SMAname] - (df["{}".format(ric)].rolling(SMA).std())*2     
    return df

dfs={}

for ric in rics:
    df = add_SMA_bands(data,ric)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    dfs[ric]=df

for ric in rics:
    dfs[ric]["OVER"] = np.where(dfs[ric][ric]<dfs[ric]["LowerBand_{}".format(ric)],1, (np.where(dfs[ric][ric]>dfs[ric]["UpperBand_{}".format(ric)],1,0)))
    dfs[ric]["OVER"][dfs[ric]["OVER"]==0]=np.nan
```

Comment: Seems like you're working on Refinitv Eikon data. A data sample would be great.